# How to generate a gpx file by using Python?

Tags: python, trace, gpx

I have a **.trace** file and I have generated it to **.kml** file. But, now I think that I need an **gpx** file to plot the data on to a map with speeds.

How to generate a **gpx** file from **.trace** file by using Python?

I am new to **gpx**, please help me.

Comment: the question is a bit old. If you are looking for an information at the mean time, then you may find this package useful: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 3):

A fast search in a major search engine would have given you the answer to that question. Here is the recipe proposed by [Tim Abell](http://timwise.blogspot.fr/2014/02/converting-kml-to-gpx-with-python.html) to transform kml into gpx. He provides the script for it [freely available in Github](https://gist.github.com/timabell/8791116).

The use of the script is exemplified in the article (I'm quoting):

```
./kmlToGpx.py "25-01 12-48.kml" > "25-01 12-48.kml.gpx"
```

It might also be worth taking a look into other packages such as [GpxPy](http://www.trackprofiler.com/gpxpy/index.html), [Openxc](http://python.openxcplatform.com/en/master/tools/gps.html), or [GpxData](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gpxdata).